# Java code execution time issue

Tags: java, python, performance, collections

I have the following code modeling a lightweight framework for a vertex in my study of network diffusion. The initial prototype was from a framework in python, which I translated into Java. The issue I have is that while this code runs much faster than its python version up to 10000 vertices, for a larger number of vertices (100,000+), it grinds to a halt. In fact the python version executed in 1.2 minutes, while the java build didn't return even after 7 minutes of execution. I am not sure why the same code is breaking down at a larger number of vertices and I need help on fixing the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vertex
{
  private int id;
  private HashMap<Integer, Double> connectedTo;
  private int status;

  public Vertex(int key)
  {
    this.id = key;
    this.connectedTo = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    this.status = 0;
  }

  public void addNeighbour(int nbr, double weight)
  {
    this.connectedTo.put(nbr, weight);
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public double getWeight(int nbr)
  {
    return this.connectedTo.get(nbr);
  }

  public int getStatus()
  {
    return this.status;
  }

  public Set<Integer> getConnections()
  {
    return this.connectedTo.keySet();
  }

//testing the class

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int noOfVertices = 100000;

    Vertex[] vertexList = new Vertex[noOfVertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++) {
        vertexList[i] = new Vertex(i);
    }

    for (Vertex v : vertexList) {
        int degree = (int)(500*Math.random()); //random choice of degree 
        int neighbourCount = 0; // count number of neighbours built up

        while (neighbourCount <= degree) {
            int nbr = (int) (noOfVertices * Math.random()); // randomly choose a neighbour
            double weight = Math.random(); // randomly assign a weight for the relationship
            v.addNeighbour(nbr, weight);
            neighbourCount++;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

For reference, the python version of this code is as follows:

```
import random

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, key):
      self.id = key
      self.connectedTo = {}

    def addNeighbor(self, nbr, weight=0):
      self.connectedTo[nbr] = weight

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' \
          + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

    def getConnections(self):
      return self.connectedTo.keys()

    def getId(self):
      return self.id

    def getWeight(self, nbr):
      return self.connectedTo[nbr]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  numberOfVertices = 100000
  vertexList = [Vertex(i) for i in range(numberOfVertices)] # list of vertices

  for vertex in vertexList:
    degree = 500*random.random() 
    # build up neighbors one by one
    neighbourCount = 0 

    while neighbourCount <= degree:
        neighbour = random.choice(range(numberOfVertices))
        weight = random.random() # random choice of weight
        vertex.addNeighbor(neighbour, weight)
        neighbourCount = neighbourCount + 1
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into this and will post some optimized code soon!

Comment: It's not easy to tell without profiling, could actually be almost anywhere. Just a quick point though: take a look at `java.util.Random` class which has a `nextInt(bound)` method (it's unlikely to be a sizeable speedup, but still).

Comment: Found the solution and posted it below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very interesting problem, and I believe I learned something new as well.  I tried optimizing the code in different ways, such as utilizing a parallel stream as well as using `ThreadLocalRandom` which can be up to three times faster than `Random`.  However, I finally discovered the main bottleneck: allocated memory to the JVM.

Because you have so many elements being added to your `Map` (worst case is 500,000 with 100,000 vertices), you'll require a lot of memory (heap space).  If you allow the JVM to dynamically allocate memory, then the program will take a very long time to execute.  The way that I solved this was to pre-allocate memory to the JVM (specifically 3 GB) by applying `-Xms3G` as a VM Argument to the program's Run Configuration which can be done in your IDE or via the terminal.

I've also optimized your code a bit which I will post below (it completes in just a few seconds for me):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {

    private static final ThreadLocalRandom RANDOM = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noOfVertices = 100_000;

        Vertex[] vertexList = new Vertex[noOfVertices];

        IntStream.range(0, noOfVertices).parallel().forEachOrdered(i -> {
            vertexList[i] = new Vertex(i);

            int degree = (int) (500 * RANDOM.nextDouble()); // random choice of degree

            for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++) {
                int nbr = (int) (noOfVertices * RANDOM.nextDouble()); // randomly choose a neighbor

                vertexList[i].addNeighbour(nbr, RANDOM.nextDouble());
            }
        });
    }

}

class Vertex {

    private int id;

    private Map<Integer, Double> connectedTo;

    private int status;

    public Vertex(int id) {
        this.id = id;

        this.connectedTo = new HashMap<>(500);
    }

    public void addNeighbour(int nbr, double weight) {
        this.connectedTo.put(nbr, weight);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public double getWeight(int nbr) {
        return this.connectedTo.get(nbr);
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getConnections() {
        return this.connectedTo.keySet();
    }

}
```

I'm not sure of the explicit consequences regarding using `ThreadLocalRandom` in a multithreaded environment, but you can switch it back to `Math#random` if you'd like.

Comment: A rather elegant solution, something that I didn't consider. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: @buzaku You're welcome, I honestly didn't know that allocating heap space can play a role in performance, but I'm glad your problem is fixed!